# Best practice for 1:many joins in Codeigniter fat model, skinny controller?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

Say I need to display a list of `users` and each `user` which can have many `user_roles`.

The list needs to display:
id, username, roles in text eg.

```
1 | john | member, moderator, admin
```

I have three tables, namely:

1. `user` Contains the user info
2. `user_role` Contains the roles i.e. user_role.id and user_role.name
3. `user_user_role` A joining table i.e. user_id, role_id

User list controller:

```
function list_users(){
    // Should I join here?
    $this->user_model->find_users();
}
```

User model:

```
function find_users(){
    // Should I join here?
    return $this->db->get('user');
}
```

Ignore the incompleteness of the code above, I am just trying to communicate the concept.

**Do I do a join on the model or controller level?**

My concerns are:

1. Trying to achieve fat model, skinny controller.
2. If I do the join on the model level, the model function, as it is too specific, is not likely to be reused elsewhere.
3. If I do the join on the controller level, the model is kept generic (which is good)

Comment: And what is the actual problem to have one more method in model? You can use generic class like in `APPPATH . 'MY_Model.php'` with all usually needed methods, than extend specific model from it. Check [this one](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model) for example.

Comment: @Tpojka: You misunderstand. There's no problem with one more method in the model and I already do extend from a core model. The issue here is writing a method in the model so specific to the controller use case that it's not going to be reused elsewhere.

Comment: Not sure, maybe I misunderstood. But I still see it as one query that can be dedicated to one method. Nothing wrong in that: something like `SELECT user.username, group_concat(user_role.name separator ', ') FROM user_user_role JOIN user_role ON user_role.user_role_id=user_user_role.user_role_id JOIN user ON user.user_id=user_user_role.user_id WHERE user_id= ?` That's exact point of my mentioning of one more method. It's how I would use it. Maybe doens't help you, than I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice, you should always put all storage-related logic under model level. A controller should only know how to call model's methods and pass arguments from the HTTP request.

If you have JOINs and want to reuse the generated fragment, you can create a shared method and invoke it on demand. For example:

```
class UserModel
{
    // ....

    public function appendJoin($db)
    {
        $db->findUsers()->join(....) 
    }

    // ....
}
```

And then you can re-use that in controllers.

Comment: I see what you mean. From what it looks here, the controller is where I call the final result()/result_array() active record methods, is that how it's done?

Comment: @komirad yes exactly. The shared method's job is to append a data on existing objects. This is what makes it reusable and at the same time you keep the storage logic in a model.

Answer (score 1):

You should make normally database related function in Model, so you can reuse it.
But yes, you can use database related function($db->findUsers()->join(....) ) in your controller for achieve your goal and its not effected with speed of database query execution etc...